# Convert string to date in kotlin

Tags: date, kotlin

could you help me?

I get a string of type `01092020`, how could I convert to date type in `01/09` format, just month and year?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `DateTimeFormatter` as follows:

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val dateString = "01092020"

    val readingFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy")
    val date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, readingFormatter)

    val writingFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/yy")
    val formattedDate = date.format(writingFormatter)
    print(formattedDate)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can substring your string and break into month and year e.g DDMMYYYY

```
val dateStr = "01092020"
val dd = dateStr.substring(0..1)
val mm = dateStr.substring(2..3)
val yyyy = dateStr.substring(4 until dateStr.length)

val DDYY = "$dd/$yyyy"
val mmYYYY = "$mm/$yyyy"
```